# Android Найти файлы с расширением ttf

Tags: android, запрос, saf

Ищу возможность получить файлы с расширением "ttf". Эти файлы уже на устройстве. Делаю запрос:

```
String[]pr = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};

 Uri quest = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

 String select = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE+"=?";
 String[]args = new String[]{"application/x-font-ttf"};

 Cursor c = getContext().getContentResolver().query(quest, pr, select, args, null);
```

В итоге ничего не получаю, так как потом выяснилось, что такой тип не распознается, то есть свободном запросе, у тех файлов что мне нужны тип "null".
Далее пытался найти нужные файлы путем перебора, но "DISPLAY_NAME" тоже возвращает "null", из-за этого отделить их по окончанию(.ttf) тоже не получается.
После всего этого решил обратиться через SAF с таким запросом:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/x-font-opentype");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST);
```

Тоже ничего не получаю. Вот если тип я обозначаю как "application/octet-stream" то получаю помимо нужных файлов и другие. В общем если кто сталкивался с подобным подскажите. И да, запрос в ContentResolver MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA делал, но это устаревающий метод. Зная папку, например Download с помощью File делал, и это тоже устаревающий способ. Остается DocumentFile но он медленный, да и плюс пользователю много лишних действий делать. Если есть альтернатива всему выше перечисленному буду рад.

Answer (score 1):

Для открытия файлов с таким расширением нужно изменить [тип](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) файлов:

```
application/x-font-ttf
```

и при открытии его передавать:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/x-font-ttf");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

Так же вот есть вопросы по данной тематике: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034375/how-to-send-an-intent-to-select-ttf-file-with-any-file-explorer), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473596/trouble-with-action-get-content-and-ttf-files) и [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45705679/typeface-createfromfile-file-not-found).